# I'm getting error - We only support linking to files in your organization - Help

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, administration, sitepages

I'm getting this error when simply trying to add an image to a post from an image that's not in SharePoint via a link.

I have also added the URL to the html field security. Any ideas or is this by design?

[image]

Comment: I think this is by design in SharePoint now. You can provide links to images uploaded in your SharePoint site/tenant.

Comment: Thanks and great to know

Comment: You're welcome. I have added it as an answer below with some explanation. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Have you tried the method below? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, Microsoft recently made changes to SharePoint online which does not allow using external links for images in image web part.

Images from the following domains are allowed:

1. Primary Microsoft 365 tenant domain
2. Configured multi-geo domains and vanity domains (`company.sharepoint.com`)

So, you can upload images to your SharePoint site/tenant and use those to link inside image web parts in SharePoint online OR use Stock images wherever possible.